# How to test whether log compaction is working or not in Kafka?

Tags: message-queue, apache-kafka, retention, stream-compaction

I have made the changes in server.properties file in Kafka 0.8.1.1 i.e. added `log.cleaner.enable=true` and also enabled `cleanup.policy=compact` while creating the topic.
Now when I am testing it, I pushed the following messages to the topic with following (Key, Message).

- Offset: 1 - (123, abc);
- Offset: 2 - (234, def);
- Offset: 3 - (345, ghi);
- Offset: 4 - (123, changed)

Now I pushed the 4th message with a same key as an earlier input, but changed the message. Here log compaction should come into picture. And using Kafka tool, I can see all the 4 offsets in the topic. How can I know whether log compaction is working or not? Should the earlier message be deleted, or the log compaction is working fine as the new message has been pushed. 
Does it have to do anything with the `log.retention.hours` or `topic.log.retention.hours` or `log.retention.size` configurations? What is the role of these configs in log compaction.
P.S. - I have thoroughly gone through the Apache Documentation, but still it is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the log compaction is visible only when the number of logs reaches to a very high count eg 1 million. So, if you have that much data, it's good. Otherwise, using configuration changes, you can reduce this limit to say 100 messages, and then you can see that out of the messages with the same keys, only the latest message will be there, the previous one will be deleted. It is better to use log compaction if you have full snapshot of your data everytime, otherwise you may loose the previous logs with the same associated key, which might be useful.

Comment: how can this be done via the command line tools provided by Kafka?

Comment: If you're wondering how to check how many messages you have, you could check the oldest offset with something like `kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -e -t my-topic -o beginning -c1 -f '%o\n'`, which will show you the oldest offset.

Answer (score 16):

even though this question is a few months old, I just came across it doing research for my own question. I had created a minimal example for seeing how compaction works with Java, maybe it is helpful for you too:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f78184eaeec3ee82b15182aec24a432a

Furthermore, consulting the documentation, I used the following configuration on a topic level for compaction to kick in as quickly as possible:

```
min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01
cleanup.policy=compact
segment.ms=100
delete.retention.ms=100
```

When run, this class shows that compaction works - there is only ever one message with the same key on the topic.

With the appropriate settings, this would be reproducible on command line.

Comment: I would add to this if you don't fill at last 1 `segment` (Topic->Partition->Segment) no compaction can occur. Assuming segment.ms=100 and you write < `segement.bytes=1GB` within the first 100ms of your test, then you will only have exactly 1 segment and your data won't get compacted. Either make sure that you write to the same partition during a longer period than `segment.ms` or set `segment.bytes` to a lower value, so that not all your data fits into 1 segment.

Comment: Forcing a segment roll every 100ms is ok for a test but will be horribly inefficient in production. The default is 604800000 ms (7 days).

Answer (score 1):

It is a good point to take a look also on `log.roll.hours`, which by default is 168 hours. In simple words: even in case you have not so active topic and you are not able to fill the max segment size (by default 1G for normal topics and 100M for offset topic) in a week you will have a closed segment with size below `log.segment.bytes`. This segment can be compacted on next turn.

Answer (score 1):

In order check a Topics property from CLI you can do it using Kafka-topics cmd :

https://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/14aev0snbd/command-line-tool-for-topic-metadata

Comment: This might show `cleanup.policy=compact`, but doesn't verify the topic actually **getting** compacted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with kafka-topics CLI.
I'm running it from docker(`confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:6.0.0`).

```
$ docker-compose exec kafka kafka-topics --zookeeper zookeeper:32181 --describe --topic count-colors-output
Topic: count-colors-output  PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: cleanup.policy=compact,segment.ms=100,min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01,delete.retention.ms=100
    Topic: count-colors-output  Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
```

but don't get confused if you don't see anything in Config field. It happens if default values were used. So, unless you see `cleanup.policy=compact` in the output - the topic is not compacted.